# Inserting value showing in <span> into the database not working

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am trying to insert a value showing in span into a database. I am using the code shown here https://jsfiddle.net/ffL58e1d/2/ and have added a submit button to post to database.

I am getting a new line and on clicking submit, I get the message "Ok" but in the database, the price field shows blank while an id gets inserted. I am unsure what I am doing wrong or missing, I have tried to make changes, do an onclick submit etc but nothing is working. Please see below:

```html
<html>

<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <form method="post">
  <div class="products">
   <input type="checkbox" data-price="1000" value="1" name="product_ids[]" id="product_id_1">
   <input type="checkbox" data-price="1200" value="2" name="product_ids[]" id="product_id_2">
   <input type="checkbox" data-price="1300" value="3" name="product_ids[]" id="product_id_3">
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="products">
   <input type="checkbox" data-price="1000" value="1" name="product_ids[]" id="product_id_1">
   <input type="checkbox" data-price="1200" value="2" name="product_ids[]" id="product_id_2">
   <input type="checkbox" data-price="1300" value="3" name="product_ids[]" id="product_id_3">
  </div> -->

  <div class="payment_options">
   <input type="radio" data-price-modifier="1.0" value="1" name="payment_option_id" id="payment_option_id_1"
    checked>
   <input type="radio" data-price-modifier="0.9" value="2" name="payment_option_id" id="payment_option_id_2">
   <input type="radio" data-price-modifier="0.8" value="3" name="payment_option_id" id="payment_option_id_3">
  </div>

  <span id="final_price"></span>
  <input name="total" type="hidden" id="total" value="" />

  <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Add">
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
   $price = $_POST['total'];
   $query = "INSERT INTO demo (price) VALUES ('".$price."')";
   if (mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
    echo "Ok";
   } else {
    echo "Not ok";
   }
  }
  ?>
 </form>

 <script>
  var total = $('#final_price').html();
 $('#total').val(total);

 $('.products input, .payment_options input').on('change', function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.products').find('input:checked').each(function() {
   sum += $(this).data('price') * $('.payment_options').find('input:checked').data(
    'price-modifier');
  });
  $('#final_price').text(sum);
 });


 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My database shows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUAVx.png)

Please advise how I can get the value inserted to database.

**Note: This is a test code and relevant amendments will be made before code is used on my website.**

Comment: You need to update `$("#total").val()` whenever you update the span, since the total is what gets submitted in the form.

Comment: I am unsure of what you mean, can you please show what I need to add and where. I am still learning JS therefore unsure what needs to be changed.

I am getting the value "0" in database, how do I get the span value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the hidden input whenever the total price changes. So add `$("#total").val(sum)` to the change handler.

```js
var total = $('#final_price').text();
$('#total').val(total);

$('.products input, .payment_options input').on('change', function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.products').find('input:checked').each(function() {
    sum += $(this).data('price') * $('.payment_options').find('input:checked').data(
      'price-modifier');
  });
  $('#final_price').text(sum);
  $("#total").val(sum);
});
```

Comment: Ohhh...thanks a lot, really appreciate your quick response. This will save me having to have multiple relationships for attributes in my database and the different price values for each combination.

How do I give a trophy on this page :)